# Image fetched by Perl LWP not getting displayed in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: perl, cgi, coldfusion-8, lwp

I used perl LWP module to fetch an image from a URL.

**CGI FILE(say img.cgi)**

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => $timeout );
my $respons = $ua->request(POST $url, Authorization => $auth_header);
if ($respons->is_success) {
  $ImgContent = $respons->decoded_content;
}
print $ImgContent;
```

Then I am calling above CGI as an http request, using cold fusion:

**img_display.cfm** file

```
<cf_http method="POST" url="img.cgi" timeout="60" throwonerror="no" local="yes">
....
</cf_http>
<cfoutput>
   #cfhttp.filecontent#
</cfoutput>
```

Whenever I hit the URL ......./img_display.cfm, from internet explorer browser, the browser displays the image perfectly.

However whenever I hit the same URL from Chrome or FireFox, instead of image, browser display, some weird characters(equivalent to the image opened in note pad).

```
ÿØÿàJFIFSÿþ4Created using the Colosseum Builders JPEG libraryÿÀ&ŠÿÛ„  " "  ÿÄ{  !"t³Ô#1468UWv–²´Ó27AQVu”•$5BXfs“¦Ñ%3DRTb‘±aµ&qr†—¡Ò CGw‚„ÃÿÚ?úF4cM®ž¦Ý=sÓÜJléXÕ½é±F'p£6¤dJ‘*ªªª÷ª­oÁ:Yói†}^‹øtö ÒÏ›L3êô_Ã§°N–|ÚaŸW¢þ=‚t³æÓú½ðéì¥Ÿ6˜gÕè¿‡O`,ù´Ã>¯Eü:{égÍ¦õz/áÓØ'K>m0Ï«ÑžÁ:Yói†}^‹øtö
```

I have no idea, why IE displays image while chrome and Firefox displays image code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change last line in CGI for `print CGI::header("image/jpeg").$ImgContent;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the string representation of the binary image data. The browser is displaying that because it does not know it's an image.

You need to print the [MIME-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image) of the image in the [HTTP header](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#CREATING-A-STANDARD-HTTP-HEADER) and set your output to [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html).

```
my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header('image/jpeg');
binmode STDOUT;
print $ImgContent;
```

Comment: Correct mime type is: `image/jpeg` not `img/...`!